# Location of VS Code preferences

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, dart

My cat jumped onto my keyboard while I was coding in Dart using VS Code. The result was an enormous increase in font size for both the editor and the sidebar. To no avail I tried **Ctrl -**. I was unable to access settings because the large font size made navigating in settings impossible.

In despair, I uninstalled VS Code, Flutter, and Dart. Using an administrator account (Win 7) I downloaded all three and reinstalled. I opened VS Code and found that the font size was restored. But when I switched user to my normal standard user account and opened VS Code, the font size was as it was before I reinstalled the software. This leads me to the belief that either a preferences file or registry entries had preserved my settings on a user-by-user basis. But where are  these settings actually stored.

I do not normally use administrator privileges. They are reserved for system wide operations. It was only serendipitous that I found the two settings.

Thanks,

Answer (score 71, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Docs: Settings file locations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

> By default VS Code shows the Settings editor, but you can still edit
>   the underlying settings.json file by using the Open Settings (JSON)
>   command or by changing your default settings editor with the
>   workbench.settings.editor setting.
>
> Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:
>
> - Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
> - macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
> - Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`
>
> The workspace setting file is located under the .vscode folder in your root folder.
>
> > Note: In case of a Multi-root Workspace, workspace settings are
> >     located inside the workspace configuration file.

According to [Microsoft Docs: Persisted Zoom Level](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility#_persisted-zoom-level) the entry you are looking for is: `window.zoomLevel`

Comment: I was going to report that I found the same. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no `Code` folder under `Application Support` for me.

Comment: That is interesting. Do you have ever started code? I think the file is created on first start.

Comment: @brentonstrine Check if you're opening the right Library folder. In MacOS, the user’s Library folder (`~/Library`) is different than the `/Library` folder at the top-level of the hard drive. The user's Library folder is hidden by default: you can view it by opening Finder, pressing command+shift+G, typing `~/Library` in the box, and hitting Enter.

Comment: For example, in ZSH and macOS do not forget to wrap it with quotes like: `vim "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json"` because in this case, it will try to open a non-existing file.

Comment: Official Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations

Comment: on linux I noticed there is also a directory called `~/.vscode` but I'm not sure why some stuff is in there and not in `~/.config/Code`

Answer (score 6):

For MAC users its:

`/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Code/User/`

and if you have a profile created in VS Code Profiles:

`/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Code/User/profiles/{profileNumber}/`

Its hidden so try to directly do a "**Go to folder**" from Finder app.