# How can I completely reinstall VSCode on MacOS?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this problem: [VS Code Terminal opens, then crashes and disappears after pressing kill button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70046348/vs-code-terminal-opens-then-crashes-and-disappears-after-pressing-kill-button)

Here's the issue I opened on Github:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137576

That's why I would like to try reinstalling VSCode. I just deleted the program from the program folder (Mac OS) and downloaded VSCode again but all the settings are the same and the error still occurs.

Is there a way to completely reinstall it?

Comment: Did you also delete the settings.json file? [Location of VS Code preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53841945/1115360).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to completely uninstall vscode on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vscode-on-mac)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I deleted this settings.json file completely, the only thing that is new in there is this: {
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "terminal.integrated.confirmOnExit": "always"
}

Comment: @GinoMempin I will try the steps in the linked article

Comment: So it did reset, which answers the question. But it doesn't solve the shell problem which I was hoping to solve with the reinstall. Maybe someone has an answer to that problem with the shell?

Comment: I just can't use the terminal in VSCode which is bad as I can't work on my project anymore

Comment: If you log into macOS as a different user, does it work?

Comment: I only have one account, what can I do then? Should I backup the Mac and reinstall the MacOS completely? It's driving me crazy

Comment: I'm sure it has to something with the shell, the environment path or something. I opened other flutter projects and there is the same error. Also in AndroidStudio the terminal can't be opened. Is there something like a repair command for the shell?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you very much Andrew, I just created a second user account and the problem is gone there. Now, as the shell error is gone there, what do I have to look for in my main account? Where is the problem with the shell?

Comment: This is what is in my .zshrc file: export PATH="$PATH:/Users/finnborchers/flutter_api/flutter/bin"
alias pip=/usr/bin/pip3
source ~/.zshrc

Comment: @Finn Have you seen [Troubleshoot Terminal launch failures](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch)? You now have the settings that work in your new account, so that should give you something to compare to.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you, I have seen them and I just compared the settings.json files of VSCode from my first and second account. They are just the same. I think it's not because of VSCode, because the shell also fails in AndroidStudio. Any ideas what to do next? Can I migrate my user account to a new one? By the way: The zsh is working via the terminal, just not in VSCode and AndroidStudio. Maybe this is helpful: When I launch the normal terminal it prints this: /Users/finnborchers/.zshrc:source:3: too many open files: /Users/finnborchers/.zshrc
finnborchers@Finns-MBP ~ %

Comment: @Finn Did you do step 4, enable trace logging, in the article I linked to?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks, I enabled trace logging, every time I try to click on terminal in the small window at the bottom it closes and puts out this log: https://pastebin.com/Yar9y9G8 Unfortunately I have no idea what that means and how to solve it, EDIT: There are some other errors on start, should I paste them too?

Comment: @Finn Me neither :(

Comment: @AndrewMorton Okay, but thanks a lot Andrew, I've learned a few interesting things from you, I'm sure it will help on my journey getting the terminal to work again :)