# VS Code is too big

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]
How can I fix this issue and reduce the size of VS Code?

Comment: try to clear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840644/location-of-vs-code-preferences vs code preferences if shortcut is not working

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom in and zoom out

Comment: I tried that shortcut but it didn't work as well I reinstalled the editor and still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to Zoom out or reset Zoom

- View > Appearance > Zoom In (Ctrl+=) - increase the Zoom level.
- View > Appearance > Zoom Out (Ctrl+-) - decrease the Zoom level.
- View > Appearance > Reset Zoom (Ctrl+Numpad0) - reset the Zoom level to 0.

See the docu [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility#_zoom).
*Note:* the keyboard shortcuts might be different depending on your keyboard/language settings.